# Android - Firebase ServerValue.TIMESTAMP returns "{.sv=timestamp}"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I have to save **ServerValue.TIMESTAMP** in my Database but it must be a string. When I type `String.valueOf(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);` or `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.toString();` it returs "{.sv=timestamp}". I want `"1523084664300"` instead of `1523084664300`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is just a token that the server understands and translates to a number, which is the current time using its own clock.  It doesn't have a numeric value on the client.  If you want the current time in milliseconds on the client, then just use the client's native API to get that value: `System.currentTimeMillis()`

If you're trying to store numbers as strings in Realtime Database, don't.  That's not a very good solution.